# _bstr_t to char pointer and calling atof(...)

Tags: c++, com

Is this code not going to produce an error:

```
_bstr_t text=n.GetText();

 atof((char*)text)
```

Where text is a double value.

I know that the `_bstr_t` produces a `const char*` in the conversion; so I'm not sure if the `atof()` is going to work?

Comment: Does GetText return a BSTR? If not, that's a very round-about way of doing this. Why not `LPCWSTR text = n.GetText();` and use `_wtof(text)`, saving the conversion? If it does, and you then own the BSTR, does that destroy it correctly? I can't remember but I'd have guessed you'd need the brackets constructor or an attach to do that.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `_bstr_t` has `operator char*() const`, so you don't need a cast. Then, this operator calls [ConvertBSTRToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewezf1f6(VS.80).aspx) which returns a heap-allocated char array you need to `delete[]` later (see the example in the linked article), failing to do so will result in a memory leak. Finally, you should be aware that `_bstr_t` can encapsulate a null pointer which corresponds to an empty string and your program should handle such situations.

Comment: But why do the conversion at all? Why not just use `_wtof` on the raw BSTR?

Comment: I don't mind. But checking for the null BSTR is necessary anyway.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the _bstr_t class manages the memory with an internal data structure; you should not have to free the memory yourself.

Comment: @Luke: I've looked into the SDK headers and see that it calls ConvertBSTRToString(). YMMV.

Comment: @sharptooth: I don't disagree, but that memory is managed via an internal class Data_t.  Also, the documentation for the _bstr_t operators don't say anything about freeing the memory.  If you free it yourself you will end up double-freeing.

@Rup: That is somewhat dangerous as BSTR is not guaranteed to be NULL-terminated and may in fact contain embedded NULLs.  In practice, however, _bstr_t is usually used to wrap NULL-terminated strings (and I think it explicitly NULL-terminates, though I'm not 100% positive).

Comment: @Luke you are correct, you usually do not need to manage memory associated with a _bstr_t.  (You can call Detach to take ownership of the internal BSTR, but the char* you cannot take ownership of.)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me it is absolutely safe to use `_wtof(text)` (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hc25t012.aspx) to make the conversion which you need.

@sharptooth: In general `BSTR` data must not be always zero-terminated string. But corresponds to description of the `_bstr_t` class (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zthfhkd6.aspx):

> A _bstr_t object encapsulates the BSTR
> data type. The class manages resource
> allocation and deallocation through
> function calls to SysAllocString and
> SysFreeString and other BSTR APIs when
> appropriate.

Only data allocated with SysAlloc-functions other as `SysAllocString` can be not zero-terminated. The function `SysAllocString` allocate always additional two bytes and fill there with L'\0'. To read more information about this subject I refer to [Eric’s complete guide to BSTR semantics](https://ericlippert.com/2003/09/12/erics-complete-guide-to-bstr-semantics/).